Removing an entry from organizaion on AWS - will it delete that organization completely or only the billing for that organization wont be billed to me
I have an account on AWS whose bill is being charged to another AWS account for whom I use to work. Now I want to pay the bill myself. If the organization under whom my account is added as a organization removes my account from his organization - will this solve the issue.
I believe I will be able to use my organization (AWS account) normally, no EC2 etc will be affected and only billing to that organization will be stopped.
Am I correct?

Yes, you are right! You can leave the Organization or ask the Management Account to remove you from the Org. All your resources in your child account remain unaffected.
